# Netbeans 7.4 Apache server error

Tags: apache, netbeans-7.4

I have installed netbeans 7.4 with glassfish and Apache server (included in netbeans). My Netbeans working fine up to date I installed Eclipse mars. After installation of Eclipse mars, when I am running project in Netbeans it is asking for username and password for Apache server and glassfish server is not listed in properties. Glassfish is not available in Netbeans now and I am not able to run my existing projects due to this username and password as I have never gave any username and password for Apache.[image]

Comment: To work around the passworded access, see [here](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html#Configuring_Manager_Application_Access). I don't understand `glassfish server is not listed in properties` : do you mean that somehow the registration of Glassfish under Services-->Servers got erased?

Comment: It means I had glassfish and apache both installed in netbeans. and now glassfish is not visible in myproject > properties>run>server.
It is showing only Apache option. Before that I had 2 option there. Glassfish and Apache.

Comment: That's extremely odd, to my knowledge an Eclipse installation should not tamper with a preexisting Netbeans installation. You can easily re-add your Glassfish server (unless somehow it got deinstalled) by going to Services-->Servers, rightclick, add.